# Get the object in an array of object with the key

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

So I have an array of objects and I want to get the object with the key "Z".

Obviously I can just loop through the array and check each key one by one and grab the one which matches, but I was thinking that there is probably a better way than my current approach:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (Object.keys(data[i]).toString() == "z") {
        return data[i].z;
        break;
    }
}
```

My data:

```
"data": [
  { "X": { "foo": "bar1" } },
  { "Y": { "foo": "bar2" } },
  { "Z": { "foo": "bar3" } }
]
```

Desired Output:

```
{
  "foo": "bar3"
}
```

Comment: There is no better way, if you don't know where the key is, you have to iterate and look for it

Comment: Reorganize your data into a single object instead of an array of objects.

Comment: A javascript object is a map. Map lookup is O(1). Array lookup is O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an array of objects, you could replace it with an object:

```
"data": {
  "X": { "foo": "bar1" },
  "Y": { "foo": "bar2" },
  "Z": { "foo": "bar3" }
}
```

And then access your object like so:

```
data['Z']
```

as you can see, much neater.

I'm guessing you used an array originally for easy appending and so on, but it's just as easy with an object:

```
data['A'] = { "foo": "bar4" };
```

will create key `"A"` in data, and you can still loop through your object using `for (... in ...)` loops, i.e:

```
for (key in data) {
  console.log(data[key].foo);
}
```

should print

```
bar1
bar2
bar3
bar4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash, you could do something like:

```
var collection = [
    { X: { foo: 'bar1' } },
    { Y: { foo: 'bar2' } },
    { Z: { foo: 'bar3' } }
];

_(collection)
    .chain()
    .find(_.ary(_.partialRight(_.has, 'Z'), 1))
    .values()
    .first()
    .value()
// → { foo: 'bar3' }
```

An outline of what this chain is doing:

1. [chain()](https://lodash.com/docs#prototype-chain): Enables explicit chaining. Otherwise, `find()` will return an unwrapped object, and we still have actions to perform.
2. [find()](https://lodash.com/docs#find): We pass in a callback that checks for the existence of the `Z` key. The callback itself is constructed using higher-order function utilities:

   - [ary()](https://lodash.com/docs#ary): Restricts the number of arguments passed to the function. We do this here because `find()` passes arguments that we don't care about to our callback.
   - [partialRight()](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight): Provides the `'Z'` argument to the `has()` function. This is the rightmost argument, meaning that each item in the collection is passed as the *first* argument.
   - [has()](https://lodash.com/docs#has): Returns true if the `Z` key exists on an object.
3. [values()](https://lodash.com/docs#values): We don't care about the object key, only it's values.
4. [first()](https://lodash.com/docs#first): The `values()` function returns a collection, but we only want the first item in it. There should only ever *be* one item in the collection.